# Oracle Hadoop Connectors vs Sqoop

Tags: hadoop, jdbc, sqoop

I have used Sqoop to ingest data from Oracle to Hadoop and it worked well. It took only 4 mins to bring 86 million records from Oracle to Hive table without using partitions on Sqoop. Can anyone give some details about Oracle Hadoop connectors, Will it perform better than Sqoop?

Comment: As per Oracle documentation:Oracle Loader for Hadoop is a MapReduce program that runs on the Hadoop cluster to pre-process the data. It can partition, sort, and convert data into Oracle data types in preparation for the load. This offloads some database cycles on to Hadoop, so that less database CPU is used during the load itself. In the online mode the pre-processed data is directly loaded into the database. In the offline mode Oracle Loader for Hadoop writes out the pre-processed data as data pump files on HDFS. There are two load options in the online mode, JDBC and direct path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most of connectors would have the performance close to same as you'll have have a set of MapReduce jobs on the very end of your workflow and this would play the main role in your overall performance.

Oracle provides a set of different connectors for accessing the Hive and you could check a nice overview about standard solutions but I doubt that on the very end you will expect significant performance differences other then you see in Sqoop:

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E37231_01/doc.20/e36961/start.htm#BDCUG119

Sqoop is a generic tool for working with the relational databases from Hadoop realm, and it is  not limited by Oracle only. Besides it has an integration with other Hadoop solutions like Oozie for making complicated workflows, which makes it a good candidate over other types of connectors.

Personally myself I prefer Sqoop for Hadoop-driven import-export operations and connector approach for querying the data in Hadoop.

Answer (score 0):

Sqoop will leverage a standard JDBC connection.  Oracles connector will work with a fastloader/fastexport class integrated into the sqoop connection.  It should be faster that Sqoop.